# ActionFunction rerender messing with Pagereference

Tags: rerender, actionfunction, pagereference, apex-param

I have a javascript method on my vf page which is called by a save button. This method performs some calculations, collects some data, and sends them to the save method in my controller as parameters using `actionFunction`.

```
 <script>
     function validate() {
        var somevar1 = //some calculation
        var somevar2 = //some calculation

        save(somevar1, somevar2);
     }
</script>

<apex:actionFunction name="save" action="{!saveRecord}">
     <apex:param name="somevar1" value=""/>
     <apex:param name="somevar2" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

In my controller

```
public Pagereference saveRecord() {
     Custom__Obj__c obj = new Custom__Obj__c();
     obj.some__field1__c = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('somevar1');
     obj.some__field2__c = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('somevar2');
     insert obj;

    Pagereference p = new Pagereference('/' + obj.Id);
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
}
```

Now here's my problem.

If - I do not put any rerender=" " in actionFunction then when I save the record I get redirected to the saved record page, BUT those two params somevar1 and somevar2 come in as null. So I end up saving the record but with null values for those two fields.

If - I do put rerender=" " in my actionFunction then when I save the record I DO NOT get redirected to the save record page, it still keeps me in the vf page, BUT those two params somevar 1 and somevar2 come in with their values.

Is this a salesforce bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way out of this?

Comment: I have observed this lately as well that having the rerender in the action function prevents the page reference from taking you to the new page. I do not recall this happening before.

Comment: see http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html for alternative way of passing params to apex methods

Comment: The alternative way does not work for me as I still need to send the user to saved record page after save button is clicked. Also, I cannot get rid of my javascript function as it is doing some important tasks.

Answer (score 2):

So I have to do a workaround for this. I am still keeping my rerender since it returns the params I need, but I am now redirecting the page using javascript.

```
 <apex:actionFunction name="save" action="{!saveRecord}" rerender="" oncomplete="redirect('{obj.Id}');">
    <apex:param name="somevar1" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="somevar2" value=""/>
 </apex:actionFunction>
```

In my script

```
 var redirect = function(objId) {
          window.href.location = '/' + objId;
 }
```

And it then redirects me to the saved object page.

Answer (score -1):

Yes ,this problem still persists ,but we hav work arround by involving action support and action functions this link should help you
http://sfdcmaniac.blogspot.in/2015/10/passing-parameters-to-controller-and.html